# Uploading Python object with Dropbox API and Pickle

Tags: python, object, file-upload, pickle, dropbox

I'm unsure how to upload a Python Results object to my dropbox. I can't use the dbx.file_upload either with pickle or just outright trying to upload it. What should I be doing?

Attempt 1:

```
with open('StochOutput', 'wb') as output_file:
    dbx.files_upload(pickle.dump(output, output_file),'StochOutput')
```

Attempt 2:

```
dbx.files_upload(output, 'StockOutput')
```

With both, I get the following error:

> dropbox.stone_validators.ValidationError: 'StockOutput' did not match pattern '(/(.|[\r\n])*)|(ns:[0-9]+(/.*)?)|(id:.*)'

1. What should be the extension of a Python object?
2. How should I code it?

Comment: To clarify a bit, aside from the matter of pickling and how to handle the data itself, the actual original `ValidationError ` error message here is just referring to the formatting of the `'StockOutput'`, in the second parameter to `files_upload`, which should be the remote path where you want to upload the file in Dropbox, which should start with a "/", so it should look like `'/StockOutput'`, or with whatever extension you want, like `'/StockOutput.ext'`.

Answer (score 0):

A saved pickle can have any extension you like.

For your code, try this:

```
dbx.files_upload(output, '/StockOutput.ext')
```

where *ext* is an extension of your choice

Comment: So, it results in a different error now.
TypeError: expected request_binary as binary type, got <class 'gillespy2.core.results.Results

Comment: Please specify how is the "output" variable is created

Comment: The "output" is the end result of package run. 
output = gillespy2.Results(data=[])